# Remove horizontal lines from "home bottom" section

Tags: formatting

I would like to remove the horizontal lines under the "home bottom" section of my site under the "latest posts" section. The lines under the titles look a bit messy. Can i remove them, or turn them white? I would like to keep the other horizontal lines in other portions of the page up.

I'm using the "featured posts widget" for this.

Wordpress/Brunch Pro/Genesis

https://olivesfordinner.com/

I googled and asked chtagpt extensively. no changes applied would work.